# How to build and debug shared libraries (.so) in vs code with g++ command

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I‘m learning to write c++ on linux with vscode. I hope I can write a task.json to build a dynamic library and then link it to my program. However, vscode can’t correctly build the library.

it keeps showing like this:
Executing task: dynamic
Starting build...
The pic link: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0oO3.png)

But when I compile the dynamic library in terminal by c++:

```
g++ ./src/Solution.cpp -I./src/header -fpic -shared -o ./lib/libSolution.so
```

I get the library successfully.

So I can not figure out where I am wrong in using vscode.

my file tree like this:

```
root/
├── bin
│   └── start
├── lib
├── src
│   ├── Solution.cpp
│   └── header
│       └── Solution.h
└── start.cpp
```

my task.json as follows:

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "dynamic",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "./src/Solution.cpp",
            "-I./src/header",
            "-fpic", "-shared",
            "-o", "./lib/libSolution.so"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "link",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-I./src/header",
            "-L./lib",
            "-lSolution",
            "-o",
            "${workspaceFolder}/bin/start"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    },
    {
        "label": "Build",
        "dependsOrder": "sequence",
        "dependsOn":[
            "dynamic",
            "link"
        ]

    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
```

}

there is my launch.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/header"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: You'd be much better off using a build system like cmake

Comment: Thank you for reply.I just want to try it for learning